# How to dispose a BannerAd if they are created in a Listview.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

Hi Im making an app and I want to implement A banner ad if every 5 item in a list,
in my stateful class I have something like this code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return BannerAd(
            size: AdSize.banner,
            adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
            listener: adState.adListener,
            request: AdRequest())
          ..load();
      }),
    );
  }
```

I am using google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.0 package

Problem is since bannerAd instance is created inside build method I cant dispose them.
And because I didnt dispose them issues appear randomly on the app;

Answer (score 1):

> You can apply modulo of the index to the position that you want to
> insert Ad.

To insert Ad after the every 5th item you can try like this `index % 5 == 0` . Below is the snippet.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Column(children: <Widget>[
               if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0) // Will insert ad after every fifth item
                  Text('Ad Banner inserted after 5th item'), // Your Ad widget
               Text('Your normal list item') // Your list item widget.
          ]);
      }),
    );
  }
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have used `Text` widget to guide you the logic :)

**Edit :**
You cannot dispose the `BannerAd` widget after it is created. It will be in the Widget tree until the parent is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and appreciate your additional help about modulos, however I actually implemented that and its just disposing that concerns me

Comment: Term `disposing` ? You are referring to ?

Comment: Yes so if I created the BannerAd = _bannerAd like that I can call, _bannerAd.dispose(); on stateful widget dispose method. But above I created instances of BannerAd inside build method, so theres no way I can implement .dispose();

Comment: Basically, my question is how can I call .dispose method for each banner that I created inside the listview?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the `dispose` that you are referring to is one of the functions available in BannerAd and that needs to be called in the `stateful` widget `@override dispose()` ?

Comment: Instead of adding the Banner ad directly try to wrap it up with the `Stateful` widget and then include it in your list builder.